# Why $f(n) = \frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+... = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^3} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})$, ($n\in N, n\ge 2$)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I think we need to prove $\frac{1}{(n+1)}+...+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}\le \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^3} $ and $\frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+5)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+6)}+...\le \frac{1}{n^5}$. I try to manipulate this formula, but just have another cubersome formula. I think to compare to $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+...$ then use geometric series formula, but not see anything.

This is a detail in the solution of problem 1.1 of the book "Problems and Solutions in Real Analysis" by Masayoshi Hata. Here, I change notation $\epsilon_n$ in the book to $f(n)$.

Comment: Put $n=1/x$, expand the left-hand side into a power series about $0$ up to order $x^4$ and replace $x$ by $1/n$.

Comment: @Gary Thank! Details from your hint (correct me if I'm wrong). First, set $f(0)=0$, so $f(x)$ is determined at $0$, and in $f'(x)$, only first term $\bigg(1/(\frac{1}{x}+1)\bigg)'\ne 0$ at $0$, so $2$-th order Taylor expansion is $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+3)^3}+O(1/n^2)$ (not $O(1/n^4)$ as in the question), and we has the answer. If nothing's wrong, please turn your comment into the answer.

Comment: More [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) should be included or perhaps an application of the hint given by Gary. If not, this question appears to be a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854) and may be closed. If the question is improved, I can post an answer that gives the coefficient for each $\frac1{n^i}$.

Comment: @ydhhat: instead of Gary answering a PSQ, which might be closed and deleted, improve the question, as mentioned above, and Gary can post his answer and I will post mine.

Comment: @robjohn , Thank! check my edited question.

Comment: @ydhhat: thank you for providing some context. I still fear that others may want more, and my answering might draw them here, so if there is any more context you can add (e.g. adding the things you have written in comments to the question) it would be useful.

Comment: @Gary This comment continues the above comment about details from Gary's hint, the $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ part is wrong (somehow, I misuse litle-o as big-O). Now, continues expand to 4-th order Taylor series of $f$, we get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We basically want the expansion of $f(n)$ around $n = \infty$. To this end we can take the expansion of $f(1/x)$ around $x = 0$. Note that we only need to go till $x^4$ since we want the expansion of $f(n)$ to end with $O(1/n^4)$. Then \begin{align*}f(1/x) &= \frac{1}{1/x + 1} + \frac{1}{(1/x + 1)(1/x + 2)} + \frac{1}{(1/x + 1)(1/x + 2)(1/x + 3)} + \cdots\\
&=\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{x^2}{(x+1)(2x + 1)} + \frac{x^3}{(x+1)(2x + 1)(3x+1)} + \cdots\\
&=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k + x^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x)^k\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-2x)^k + x^3\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x)^k\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-2x)^k\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-3x)^k + x^4\prod_{i=1}^4\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-ix)^k\\
&=(x-x^2 + x^3 - x^4 + \cdots) + (x^2 - 3x^3 + 7x^4 + \cdots) + (x^3 - 6x^4 + \cdots) + (x^4 + \cdots)\\
&= x - x^3 + O(x^4),\quad \text{as }x\to 0\end{align*}
so $f(n) = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}$
Note that
$$\begin{split}f(n) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(n+k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-t)^k}{k!}t^n \d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-t)^k}{k!}t^n \d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \e^{1-t} t^n \d t \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \e^{1-t-\e^{-t}} \e^{-nt}\d t \text{.}
\end{split}$$

(The sum and integral interchange by the monotone convergence theorem for integrals.) Note that $\e^{1-t-\e^{-t}}$ is analytic and has Maclaurin expansion

$$\e^{1-t-\e^{-t}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k \tfrac{t^k}{k!}\text{,}$$

with coefficients given by [OEIS A014182](https://oeis.org/A014182)
$$a_{(\quad)} = (1,0,-1,1,2,-9,\ldots)\text{.}$$

Then by [Watson's lemma](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.ii), the integral expression for $f(n)$ has the asymptotic expansion that one would expect by termwise integration:

$$\begin{split}f(n)=\int_0^{\infty} \e^{1-t-\e^{-t}} \e^{-nt}\d t &\sim \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{n^{k+1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^3} +\frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{2}{n^5} -\frac{9}{n^6} + O(n^{-7})\text{.}\end{split}$$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding as a geometric series gives
$$
\frac1{n+j}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(-1)^i\frac{j^{\,i}}{n^{i+1}}+\frac1{n^{m+1}}O\!\left(j^m\right)\tag1
$$
Using the Heaviside method for partial fractions yields
$$
\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{(j-1)!(k-j)!}\frac1{n+j}\tag2
$$
With $a_i=e\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{j!}j^{\,i}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}\frac1{(k-j)!}\frac1{n+j}\tag{3a}\\
&=e\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}\frac1{n+j}\tag{3b}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(-1)^i\frac1{n^{i+1}}e\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}j^{\,i}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{m+1}}\right)\tag{3c}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac1{n^i}e\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{j!}j^{\,i}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{m+1}}\right)\tag{3d}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{a_i}{n^i}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{m+1}}\right)\tag{3e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: apply $(2)$ and swap order of summation
$\text{(3b)}$: sum in $k$
$\text{(3c)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(3d)}$: substitute $i\mapsto i-1$, multiply by $\frac jj$, include the $j=0$ term
$\text{(3e)}$: apply the definition of $a_i$

Here is a method to compute the $a_i$ without the use of [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind); however, it is not apparent that these coefficients are all integers:
$$
\begin{align}
a_i
&=e\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{j!}j^{\,i}\tag{4a}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(k-j)!j!}j^{\,i}\tag{4b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(k-j)!j!}j^{\,i}\tag{4c}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^i\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(k-j)!j!}j^{\,i}\tag{4d}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^i\sum_{k=j}^i\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(k-j)!j!}j^{\,i}\tag{4e}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^i\sum_{k=0}^{i-j}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{k!j!}j^{\,i}\tag{4f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: definition
$\text{(4b)}$: $e=\sum\limits_{k=j}^\infty\frac1{(k-j)!}$
$\text{(4c)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(4d)}$: the $k^\text{th}$ difference of $j^{\,i}$ vanishes for $k\gt i$
$\text{(4e)}$: switch order of summation
$\text{(4f)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k+j$

Using Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind, however, it is easy to see that these coefficients are integers:
$$\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{#1\atop #2\right\}}
\begin{align}
a_i
&=e\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{j!}j^{\,i}\tag{5a}\\
&=e\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^i\stirtwo{i}{k}\frac{j!}{(j-k)!}\tag{5b}\\
&=e\sum_{k=0}^i\sum_{j=0}^\infty\stirtwo{i}{k}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{(j-k)!}\tag{5c}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^{i-k}\stirtwo{i}{k}\tag{5d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: definition
$\text{(5b)}$: $j^{\,i}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^i\stirtwo{i}{k}\frac{j!}{(j-k)!}$
$\text{(5c)}$: combine terms and switch order of summation
$\text{(5d)}$: sum in $j$

Thus, using $(3)$ and either $(4)$ or $(5)$, we get
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}=\frac1n+\frac0{n^2}-\frac1{n^3}+\frac1{n^4}+\frac2{n^5}-\frac9{n^6}+\frac9{n^7}+\frac{50}{n^8}-\frac{267}{n^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{10}}\right)\tag6
$$

Comment: Somewhere you have to address the fact that these are formal manipulations. For example $(1)$ is valid for $n>j$ but $j$ will eventually run through all positive integers.

Comment: @Gary: How about now?

Comment: Looks good now!